# SQL Optimistic Concurrency - Involving several tables across db

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, locking, isolation-level

Imagine scenario where we have Products table where we define ProductId, Name, Price.
Also, we have InvoicesHeader and InvoicesLines tables which gets filled as users create Invoices and add items to it.

InvoicesLine table had reference to Products table through ItemProductId FK and also has field Price for that item which initially is set to value stored in Products table for that Item but user might change when creating Invoice.

Now, there might be a case like this:

1. userA starts creating an invoice and adds ProductX to invoice items. price for the item from Products table gets populated
2. userA goes on adding other items
3. before userA finishes the invoice (which is saved all at once at the end) userB goes to Products table and changes the price for ProductX
4. userA now submits an invoice

Desirable result would be that userA is notified (upon clicking Save Invoice) that prices changed.
What is the best practice to acomplish this?

One option is to have rowversions/timestamps on Products table, get them to UI and submit them back with line items. So when saving invoices, transaction first check if rowversions of lineitems and corresponding products table records are intact. If so > proceed, if not > notify user.
Also, seems like SaveInvoices transaction should in that case hold REPEATABLE_READ isolation level on products table rows involved insuring no prices are changed during saving items to invoice.

I am wondering if there is some more elegant way to do it as this feels a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a LastValueModifiedDate datetime column in Product table and update it whenever value changed.
So, on saving the Invoice:

If current datetime < of each products' LastValueModifiedDate then it's OK to save.

If cureent datetime >= of at least one products' LastValueModifiedDate then you can inform the user what products' value is changed.

Comment: I am very reluctant to go with datetime of any kind because of several reasons. Some being: datetime precision issues, timezones, daylight saving times, etc... I can see a number of unpredictables with datetime where that comparison can go wrong. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: All the datetimes would be sql server datetime (getdate() should be stored in the Product when value changes and getdate() should be compared to this stored dates). No user client datetime.

Comment: i guess you'd like to have at least getutcdate() in that case. also, what happens when your DST goes backwards?

Comment: What do you mean? "...DST goes backwards..."

Comment: if you have getdate(), what happens when daylight saving time changes? does it affect it in any way?

Comment: You were right. You need GetUtcDate to return the UTC date that does not does not observe daylight saving time. I 'm looking into this a little bit more.